# Tautology propositions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, computer-science

Anyone knows, considering $a$, $b$ and $c$ as propositions, if those propostions below are both tautologies? What I found out yet is that they are, but im not totally sure. 
$((a∨b)∧((a→c)∨(b→c)))→c$ 
$a→((¬b→c)∨(¬b→¬c))$

Comment: The logic term is “proposition,” not “preposition.”

Comment: That's totally correct, sorry. I ll edit it.

Comment: typo in the title too

Comment: You can easily check this by means of truth-tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first statement is not necessarily true, consider when $a$ is false and $b\to c$ is false, in this case we may not have $c$.

The second one is true. Since the consequence $(¬b→c)∨(¬b→¬c)\equiv (b∨c)∨(b∨¬c)$ is always true.

Comment: oh I see, I forgot to consider this statement.

Comment: you mean if a is false, b is true and c is true, is ((a→b)→c)∧(¬b∨c) a true statement? @Luther

Comment: Exactly!!!!!!!!!

Comment: of course, since in this case, $(a→b)→c\equiv c∨¬(a→b)$ will be true as $c$ is true and $(¬b∨c)$ too. In particular, you only need $c$ to be true to make this statement true.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I will edit it @drhab

Answer (score 0):

The first one isn't even a valid statement. Suppose that $a$ is true and $c$ follows from $b$, but not necessarily from $a$. Then $c$ is not a guaranteed consequent from your premise even though the premise is true. However, you can change the second "or" to an "and," and your statement will be both valid and a tautology since it doesn't matter what your variables are.

Your second statement is a tautology. The consequent is always true, so no matter what $a$ is, the entire statement is true.

Comment: heya, I have other question, if I consider the same propositions but in the following expression: ((a→b)→c)∧(¬b∨c) only when a is false, b is true and c is true, is it a valid statement?

Comment: @Luther When I use the rule of material implication twice and distribute, I get that this is another tautology, unless there's been some misstep in my work. If I were you, I'd look up logical distribution and material implication so you can check my work for yourself and see if I'm right.